# Android studio giving me a hard time while git cloning

Tags: android, git, android-support-library

I'm coming here today because I am facing a kind of new error while doing a git clone from an android studio project.

In fact, I loaded my project into android studio but I got a 'R cannot be resolved' - Okay I know how to handle this

But I'ma facing a new error which is my android studio can't seem to load the android support library. Whenever I try to import it, even if it is included in my dependencies and that it was working perfectly fine on another computer, it says that it can't find the symbol SwipeRefreshLayout (as an example)

Did anyone here had to deal with this ? Your help would be loved ^^

Comment: What's the project build target version?

Comment: The target sdk version is 23

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your android support library version, check your gradle config file to make sure that you have the same version of the support library.